# Force ncat to send packet without closing connection

Tags: sockets, network-programming, boost-asio, netcat

I wrote a socket client using [ASIO](https://think-async.com/Asio/AsioStandalone.html) standalone library. To test the client, I downloaded the windows version of `ncat` utility from `https://nmap.org/download.html`. The client program sends a packet and wait for an acknowledgment from the server. Upon receiving the ack, client send the next packet.

**I'm running the `ncat` like this**

```
c:\> ncat -l 8801 -v
Ncat: Version 7.93 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Listening on :::8801
Ncat: Listening on 0.0.0.0:8801
Ncat: Connection from 127.0.0.1.
Ncat: Connection from 127.0.0.1:2177.
sending message-1   # this is the message received from client
ack-1               # I would like to send this msg to client without closing the connection
```

But I'm unable to send an acknowledgement from `ncat` program. Pressing enter key doesn't send the current text on the console. Pressing `ctrl-c` sends the packet but causes the `ncat` utility to close the connection as well.

Is it possible to send the current text on the console as a tcp packet using `ncat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading the man-page it does seem as if line-wise buffering is the default (and also only) option.

This means you whould expect the line to be sent when you press Enter in the terminal, signaling EOL to the `ncat`'s stdin stream.

This tells me your client code runs a composed read operation (like `async_read`) without a suitable completion condition.

Consider posting your code, or figure it out for yourself using e.g.

```
asio::async_read_until(s, buf, "\n", handler);
```

Comment: I was using `sock.async_receive(response, 0, receive_handler);`. After changing to `asio::async_read_until` my setup works fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Take away: always post the relevant code. Not everyday the crystal ball is in service.